# When REQUEST_URI can be empty?

Tags: php

I was creating router for my PHP website and came across such a method :

```
public function getURI() {
   if (!empty($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
      // do some stuff and return the result
   }
}
```

I figured out even if I request `'example.com'` - `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is not empty (it's `'/'`)

The questions are:

Why do I need to check whether the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is empty?

When `REQUEST_URI` can be empty?

Comment: Define `empty`  as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = ''` technically is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a HTTP call, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is never empty, because it's a part of the HTTP protocol.

If this function is called in CLI, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` could be empty.

**edit**

Or, as pointed by @ArtisticPhoenix, it can be changed by the user `unset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` or `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]="foo";`

Comment: What if I do `unset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` ... lol J/P, Or what if I go to`http://example.com` as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = ''` is technically empty.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You're right ! But you should not :) I will still specify it, thanks !

Comment: I was just kidding.  I did something like that before and then forgot about it, took me hours to find it.  ( it was on the $_POST though )

Comment: Yea I was wondering if it was possible to remove the trailing `/` with htaccess.  sometime people say `http://example.com` but what they mean is `http://example.com/`  because what they really have is this `http://example.com/index.php`  But that's a bit of digression for the purposes of the question, I suppose.  I just loath edge cases.